# What does "Pray, No " mean?

Tags: expressions

It goes something like this
A: did you do that?
B: pray, no .....

And another example is "Just pray no"

Comment: Where have you seen it used in this way?

Answer (score 2):

Pray in this since is used in place of "please". It is from a Shakespearean usage, if I'm correct. 'I pray you' = 'I am asking you, please' Also, prithee = 'I pray thee'. Pray basically means to ask. To super-politely ask would be to ask, and add, if it pleases you.

Comment: Does this really fit OP's second example? Though admittedly, I'm not sure anything would.

Comment: I'm sure the usage didn't _originate_ with Shakespeare, though it would have been common in his time.

Answer (score 1):

In modern usage pray means ask a deity, and by extension hope strongly. "Pray, no" would mean "I really hope I didn't", and "Just pray no" would mean "Just hope/pray that the answer is no".